# bash: parsing a number out of a text string

Tags: regex, bash

I'm writing a little bash script that scan a list of text lines, each of which has the format:

> num1 num2 num3 filename

For each line, I only want to parse out the first numerical token. This is my code:

```
printf "input line: %s\n" "${line}"
let number="${line//^[0-9]+/}"
printf "regexp parsed %s\n" "${number}"
```

Well, it does parse out the first number in the line, but also outputs an error message:

```
input line: 11531          1008      16   12555    310b /usr/bin/gresource
./statistics.sh: line 21: let: number=11531           1008      16   12555    310b /usr/bin/gresource: syntax error in expression (error token is "1008          16   12555    310b /usr/bin/gresource")
regexp parsed 11531
```

Why do I get this error message? How can I apply the regexp `$[0-9]+` on `$line` without getting the error?

Comment: Why do you need `let`?  You aren't performing any arithmetic.

Comment: Please show an example of the desired output.

Comment: I think you can do that with `sed`, `sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/'`

Comment: @agc, a desired output would be:

input line: 11531          1008      16   12555    310b /usr/bin/gresource
regexp parsed 11531

Comment: See http://rextester.com/CPCC10488 or use the regex as shown below.

Comment: If you're trying to *extract* the first word of the line by means of bash build ins, your way to go would be `${line%%[!0-9]*}`, which deletes all trailing characters from `$line` starting with the first non-digit, i.e. it only keeps the leading characters, that are digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter expansions expect patterns, not regular expressions. Further, your attempt would *remove* the number rather than capturing it. What's really happening is that `let` is converting the entire line to a number by commenting on, but ignoring, the non-numeric part of the line. (That is, it only "works" because the line actually starts with a number.)

Consider the following, using the *extended* pattern equivalent to the regular expression `[0-9]+`. Note that your regular expression, treated as a pattern, doesn't match anything.

```
$ echo "$line"
11531          1008      16   12555    310b /usr/bin/gresource
$ echo "${line//^[0-9]+/}"
11531          1008      16   12555    310b /usr/bin/gresource
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo "${line/+([0-9])}"
          1008      16   12555    310b /usr/bin/gresource
```

Use a regular expression match.

```
[[ $line =~ [0-9]+ ]] && number=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
```

Comment: Well, thanks. I'm a complete noob with bash, as you may have allraey guessed. You mentioned "Parameter expansions" in your answer. Is this  the ${something} kind of expression?

Comment: ok, as for "parameter expression", I got this man:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 0):

If the lines are all that format, use `cut`, since there'd be no need to parse for numbers:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1 <<< 'num1 num2 num3 filename'
```

Output:

```
num1
```

---

For an input file do:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1  inputfile.txt
```